# PHP/Codeigniter - For Loop [Undefined offset]

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, for-loop

```
for($i=0;$i<count($status);$i++)
{
    $conf = array(
        'source_image' => $status[$i]['full_path'],
        'new_image' => $this->upload_path . '/thumbs',
        'maintain_ratio' => true,
        'width' => 200,
        'height' => 200
    );

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $conf);
    $this->image_lib->resize();

    $this->image_lib->clear(); // complete reset    
    $this->image_lib->initialize($conf); // complete reset
}

            .
```

always keep missing the last thumbnail creation cycle. when trying **for($i=0;$i<=count($status);$i++)**. i get this notice Undefined offset

Comment: when i keep the condition as less than $status i miss an image, when i keep the condition as less than equal to the script creates a blank array.

Comment: Can you post the `var_dump` of the array, please?

Comment: Are you sure that the full_path index exists in the last item of the $status?

Comment: Pretty please (with sugar on top) don't use `count()` in a loop condition. Cache the array length in a variable before the loop.

Answer (score 2):

By using a `for` loop you are assuming that the keys of the array are contiguous, which they may not be. You are also assuming that every second level array has a `full_path` key, which it may not. Use `foreach` instead, and do an `isset()` check on the `full_path` key:

```
foreach ($status as $item)
{

    if (!isset($item['full_path'])) continue;

    $conf = array(
        'source_image' => $item['full_path'],
        'new_image' => $this->upload_path . '/thumbs',
        'maintain_ratio' => true,
        'width' => 200,
        'height' => 200
    );

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $conf);
    $this->image_lib->resize();

    $this->image_lib->clear(); // complete reset    
    $this->image_lib->initialize($conf); // complete reset
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');
$stat = array_values($status);
for($i=0;$i<count($stat);$i++)
{
$conf = array(
    'source_image' => $stat[$i]['full_path'],
    'new_image' => $this->upload_path . '/thumbs',
    'maintain_ratio' => true,
    'width' => 200,
    'height' => 200
);

$this->image_lib->initialize($conf); // complete reset
$this->image_lib->resize();

}
```